# Fastest way to check if a number is in a list of numbers

Tags: c++

I need to check whether an ID (a long integer) is in a list of  ~10,000 IDs. I need to do this about 10^9 times over on a loop, and speed is relatively important. Is using a c++ set the quickest way to do this? Something like:

```
set<long> myset;

// (Populate myset)

long id = 123456789;

if(myset.find(id) != myset.end()) {
     // id is in set
}
```

Or is there a quicker way?

Comment: Unless you want to write your own data structure specifically optimized only for your program, then yes, this is the fastest way.

Comment: If the population of the list is a one time activity and then there are multiple searches on the list, then binary search is the way to go as pointed out by @David. It offers a complexity of log2(n) (even in the worst case scenario). Only drawback is that the list needs to be sorted.

Comment: Sorting 10000 numbers take no time at all compared to a billion searches. I would go for a vector<long>, which is way more compact than a set. Each set node generally contains three pointers in addition to the data. That increases pressure on the cache.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quickest way, if your long has a limited range, is a bitmap (e.g. `vector<bool>`). If that's not doable, a `unordered_set` (hash_set) should be attempted. And if that keeps hitting worst-case, *then* use a `set`

Comment: @Frerich: It'd need to be measured. Cache thrashing vs the few extra operations.

Comment: @Erik: Indeed, I just tried it; the `std::vector<bool>` variant is much faster with MSVC10 (compiling using `/O2`). I take it all back and claim the opposite. :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand the bitmap suggestion - do you suggest populating a vector<bool> (or similar) with an entry for every possible value of the long? I'm not sure this would be feasable given my IDs go up to about 1,000,000,000. But then I did ask for speed not space! I think the unordered_set sounds like the best suggestion.

Comment: nick: If your IDs fall within a certain range, it may be feasible to use a `vector<bool>` (1 bit per element). 1 billion bits would be 256MB. If your ID's e.g never go below 900'000'000 then you'd only need a vector with 100 mill bits though.

Comment: Also, if you have 1 bill possible IDs, but just 10k actual, a custom data structure (e.g. array of pointer to vector<bool>) where each array element covers e.g. 64k IDs and is NULL if all IDs in this subrange are not present. It may be worth the trouble to get constant-time access for this.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for that. Unfortuanatly the IDs are over the full range, so vector<bool> probably isn't the solution.

Comment: @Erik Sorry didn't see your last comment. That sounds a lot more feasible, thanks for the hint.

Comment: @nick: Then try the sparse bitset suggested in my previous comment. If this as frequently accessed as your question indicates, IMO you should put as much work as needed into getting constant-time lookup.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, depending on how you generate the numbers and how many there are, it might be faster to use an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) ,sort it (you can even keep it sorted while inserting the numbers), and the use [binary search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) to check if the number is in there.

Generally, a set works fine, but there are tradeoffs. The vector has less memory overhead, and since all numbers are stored in a continuous block of memory, it might outperform a set in some situations, but you would have to test that.

Comment: Sounds to me exactly like what std::set is providing?

Comment: @ypnos: It is, with regard to complexity. However, which is faster in practice depends on other factors as well. For some sizes a naive search from begin to end could be the fastest approach.

Comment: @ypnos - externally they work the same, internally the set is probably a tree structure which is probably suboptimal for your specific case

Answer (score 1):

You can build a hash table and check in O(1) if the ID exist.

Comment: I might be wrong but the computation of the **hash** + searching the **hash** in the list probably isn't done in constant time. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @ereOn: The calculation of the hash should happen in constant time, and the 'searching' is just putting that hash value into an array index, that's how lookup tables work.

Comment: @Xeo: In (hopefully!) a few cases though, the hash function will cause collisions, so you're doing an array index and then traversing a single-linked list. So you have *amortized* constant time lookup (whereas a real lookup table gives real constant time).

Answer (score 0):

The standard, for best intentions, decided that `vector<bool>` should be specialized to be implemented as a bitset.

A bit-set is fast enough, and you have the choice also of std::bitset which is fixed size, and `boost::dynamic_bitset` of which the size is runtime defined, and is built on top of `vector<unsigned int>` anyway (It may be a template on what integral type is used).

There is no point optimising further to save you some bit-twiddling so the suggestion would be to use one of these.

By the way, I have seen a "scattered" bitmap, whereby if the value falls within a certain range it uses one, otherwise it will use a tree-style lookup. (This technique can also be used for Z-table (normal distribution CDF type) functions where you "cache" the table in memory for up to 95% or 99% of the density and use the slow-calculation for the extreme values (and I once actually had to do that).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to push it to the top, you also have the option to use a two stage approach.

1. Use a bloom filter or similar probabilistic algorithm to find out if the value is definitively NOT in the set or "maybe" in the set.
2. To see if step 1 produced a false positive, you then need to execute your more costly second stage only to those not filtered out with step 1. Over your many (you mentioned 10^9) queries, you should be done more quickly (if not too many queries are a hit...).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter for details.
Also see: [Search algorithm with minimum time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506423/search-algorithm-with-minimum-time-complexity)