# Search algorithm with minimum time complexity

Tags: algorithm, search

Is there any search algorithm with time complexity O(1)?

Search Algorithm = Finding an element x from n elements.

Comment: Define "search algorithm"

Comment: But hashtable' worse look up is not O(1).

Comment: Algorithm for finding an integer x from a given n integers would be a search algorithm.

Comment: Search algorithm on what input? An unsorted array?

Comment: @tanvi: No, that would be a very specific application of some search algorithm to a very specific kind of input. And even with that it is still not clear whether any pre-processing is allowed and counted as part of "search" time. Is it?

Comment: @tanvi: If the input is just an array and you count pre-processing time (that might be required by the search algorithm), then no, such algorithm does not exist.

Comment: @Andrey T : Pre processig is allowed and will be counted as part of "search" time. And I am talking about an algorithm which is given an input x and an array of n elements(not just integers). I know that searching through hashtable is amortized O(1). What I was asking is if there exists any search algorithm with truly O(1) complexity?

Comment: @Andrey T : If the pre processing time is not counted, then only hashtable will provide such an algorithm?

Comment: @tanvi: No, if the preprocessing time is counted, then absolutely nothing will provide `O(1)` search algorithm. Initializing the hash table, bloom filter, array etc. with your `n` elements (which is what I mean by "preprocessing") will take `O(n)` time. No way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would be surprised if a search algorithm that was deterministically O(1) existed, the good news is that you can get lookup that is arbitrarily close to 100% accurate with O(1) add and lookup operations using a bloom filter. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

Similarly, a variety of techniques exist for those sets with finite sizes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) although if those set sizes are very large problems arise in practice

However, to the general case, the answer is, to the best of my knowledge, no.  And certainly not in any practical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a huge array, so that each possible value has one slot. Storing values and looking up values has time complexity O(1).

#### Edit:

If the initialisation time is counted also, then it's absolutely impossible to make an O(1) search algorithm. Searching an array without preprocessing can never be better than O(n), and there is no way to preprocess n items in O(1).

Comment: Preparing your array (given a bunch of numbers to search in) would take `O(n)` time. I don't know whether this time counts as part of search time, considering how vague the question is.

Comment: @AndreyT: Naturally, storing n items anywhere can't take O(1).

Comment: Exactly. Which is why the question needs to be clarified. The clarifications provided by the OP so far (preprocesisng time is counted as part of the search time) naturally suggest that the `O(1)` algorithm is completely out of question.